# How to execute a system command one minute after reboot (Linux)?

Tags: linux, mount, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to run a system command such as `mount` a certain amount of time after system reboot?

My problem is that I had an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount a host disk in a Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine. A direct mount wouldn't work because of some timing issues in loading kernel modules. So I used a `noauto` option in `fstab` and added a line in `/etc/rc.local` to `mount /some_disk`.

This had worked for Ubuntu (12.04 & 14.04), but now I switched to Lubuntu. And the above no longer works. I guess it's probably because Lubuntu reboots much faster, and `rc.local` is executed early. BTW, I verified that other commands in `rc.local` execute fine. And `mount /some_disk` works when `sudo`'ed after the system is up.

So I wonder how to postpone `mount /some_disk` in a script like `rc.local`, say 1 minute after the reboot?

Note: I can do

```
sudo mount /some_disk
```

successfully seconds after reboot (GUI is up).

Comment: Use `sleep 60; mount /some_disk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. just create an init script and place it into `/etc/init.d/`.

Then register the script with the different runlevels. via the following command:

```
update-rc.d <scriptname> defaults 99 01
```

The 99 means, it is called at the very end of the boot process.

Sophisticated daemon scripts look like `/etc/init.d/skeleton`.

However, as your script is not a supposed to be a daemon at all, the following script should work.

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
  start)

    sleep 60
    # your code

    ;;
esac

quit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @D Schlachter is a good idea, but lacks in the point of the command needed to be executed as root. Nevertheless, you can use the systemwide crontab in /etc/crontab or the root's crontab,

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Please note the syntax difference between those files, since the system-wide crontab needs an extra column for the user the command will be executed as.

```
@reboot root sleep 60; mount /some_disk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cron`. Add this line to your crontab (`crontab -e`):

```
@reboot sleep 60 ; mount /some_disk
```

[[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/crontab-job-start-1-min-after-reboot)
[[2]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/)

Comment: Thanks. This however, does not seem to work. I don't know if it executes the `mount` as root, or something else is going on. I still have no mount, but I can get a mount manually seconds after reboot.